# Django query execute behaviour

Tags: django, orm

I have written this in `django`

```
a = Model.objects.all()
```

Will this query execute immediately or not?

When will this query fetch the request from the db?

Answer (score 1):

In Django the Querysets are lazy i.e. when you create a queryset, it will involve any database activity,unless the queryset is evaluated.Read this [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#) for more in depth information.

Comment: You probably meant to say "it will *not* involve any database activity"

Comment: if we write down this  a = Model.objects.all() it will not hit db? and when we print (a) then this query will hit db. is it write @AR7

Comment: Yes, the queryset will involve the database activity when you start iterating the queryset like :                                                                                       `for e in Entry.objects.all():
                print(e.headline)`